# Nothing being output in program with user input and loop

Tags: c#, loops, variables, user-input

I have been tasked to create a C# windows form app program that contains a loop where it will take user input for an upper and lower bounds and output starting at 10 and ending before the upper bounds. My program will not output anything and I am not sure what is wrong. Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Loops
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int lowerBounds, upperBounds, num;

    private void TextBoxUpperBounds_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        upperBounds = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    private void BtnOutputValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (num = lowerBounds; num < upperBounds; num++)
        {
            if (num % 10 == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
            }
            else { }

        }
    }        

    private void TextBoxLowerBounds_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lowerBounds = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can't read value from the console (`Console.ReadLIne())` when you are in a Forms application

Comment: Why are you reading the console in a text box change event? Shouldn't you be reading the value of text box i.e. TextBoxUpperBounds.Text.

Comment: So read the input with TextBoxUpperBounds.Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atomSmasher was completely correct. Here is the code that does exactly what I needed it to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Loops
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int lowerBounds, upperBounds, num;

        private void TextBoxUpperBounds_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            upperBounds = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxUpperBounds.Text);
        }

        private void BtnOutputValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (num = lowerBounds; num < upperBounds; num++)
            {
                if (num % 10 == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
                }
                else { }

            }
        }        

        private void TextBoxLowerBounds_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lowerBounds = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxLowerBounds.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code just output Multiples of 10 which are lower than upper bound.

to make your code to output the numbers between lower bound and upper bound which are greater than 10 you should use below loop:

```
for (num = lowerBounds; num < upperBounds; num++)
    {
        if (num >10 )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
        }
        else { }

    }
```